# Many third party libraries not working with android studio bumblebee update

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependencies, build.gradle

Recently I've updated my android studio to bumblebee. With this update, many of the libraries I've used in artic fox is not working. some of them is following:-

implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat'
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.1'

the question is how can I use the old library in the new update of the android studio?

Comment: Can you clarify what "not working" means? Also, are you able to build your project from the command line, without the Android Studio?

Comment: I'm facing the same thing , did you find any solution for that ?? it is a bug i guess

Answer (score 4):

The issue you are facing is really simple to solve. Just follow my steps down below.

Step: 1

On the left side of Android Studio click on the 'Gradle Script' after that go to settings.gradle

Step: 2

Copy this code and paste it inside repositories.

```
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

Paste it here.

```
 pluginManagement {
 repositories {
       gradlePluginPortal()
       google()
       mavenCentral()
     }
 }
 dependencyResolutionManagement {
     repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
         
         //paste the code here
     }
 }
```

After that click on 'Try again or Sync'.
This may solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Lalrem Lian B Tlung your answer helped me. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad that I'm able to help.